# Ubuntu 22.04 - Web audio suddenly extremely low for some sites

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, google-chrome, youtube

Recently the audio from some websites on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop is barely audible. This happens only on my sites but not others, but happens on both Chrome and Firefox.

It even happens for different videos on youtube. (so presumably related to a codec?)

Audio in Slack is barely audible.
Audio in Google meet is barely audible.
Some videos (but not others) on youtube are barely audible.
Audio in Spotify **is** audible

The Gnome Audio Control app doesn't help.

How can I debug what on earth is going on here?

This is the debug info for a youtube video where the audio *does not* work:

```
{
  "ns": "yt",
  "el": "detailpage",
  "cpn": "EiXZQGeelK-KkuHB",
  "ver": 2,
  "cmt": "5.717",
  "fmt": "244",
  "fs": "0",
  "rt": "65.015",
  "euri": "",
  "lact": 0,
  "cl": "516646855",
  "mos": 0,
  "state": "4",
  "volume": 100,
  "cbr": "Chrome",
  "cbrver": "111.0.0.0",
  "c": "WEB",
  "cver": "2.20230320.00.00",
  "cplayer": "UNIPLAYER",
  "cos": "X11",
  "cplatform": "DESKTOP",
  "hl": "en_GB",
  "cr": "CH",
  "len": "86.261",
  "fexp": "23983296,23986033,24004644,24007246,24080738,24135310,24169501,24396645,24415864,24416290,24428638,24433679,24435245,24437577,24439361,24447748,24449113,24450367,24470719,24481771,24482081,24483085,24483088,24487345,24487565,24493698,24493736,24495841,24499792,39323074",
  "afmt": "251",
  "muted": "0",
  "docid": "sILEQ-doSos",
  "ei": "eM4ZZLuGCJS9x_AP7rav6AM",
  "plid": "AAX3asa5X1ijlKsh",
  "of": "Ch5JiyqwSURsHZqAO-oVAw",
  "vm": "CAEQARgEOjJBRlNkMkZ1VnctVTdhUC1rUk5MWl9lMy1QcldKQ29xdHB0ZXl6MnVQUTFBemRQdHJvd2JUQVBta0tESUVxdi1kQ1NnM1JmUGQ4NnhnbUU5VHlSWEltSWpXdzloc3JuVDlwQWctdERGdHBFNF9DYXBJbThPVkd4dXhUVFhRRnR6R3JxaC0ySF9waAE",
  "vct": "5.717",
  "vd": "86.261",
  "vpl": "0.000-5.717",
  "vbu": "0.000-86.261",
  "vpa": "1",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "4",
  "vns": "2",
  "vec": "null",
  "vemsg": "",
  "vvol": "1",
  "vdom": "1",
  "vsrc": "1",
  "vw": "2594",
  "vh": "1459",
  "lct": "5.717",
  "lsk": false,
  "lmf": false,
  "lbw": "2431584.225",
  "lhd": "0.012",
  "lst": "0.000",
  "laa": "itag_251_type_3_src_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_seg_8_range_1167949-1271004_time_80.0-86.3_off_0_len_103056_end_1_eos_1",
  "lva": "itag_244_type_3_src_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_seg_15_range_2997930-3035010_time_78.3-86.2_off_0_len_37081_end_1_eos_1",
  "lar": "itag_251_type_3_src_getRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_getRequestInfoForRange_seg_8_range_1167949-1271004_time_80.0-86.3_off_0_len_103056_end_1_eos_1",
  "lvr": "itag_244_type_3_src_getRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_getRequestInfoForRange_seg_15_range_2997930-3035010_time_78.3-86.2_off_0_len_37081_end_1_eos_1",
  "laq": "0",
  "lvq": "0",
  "lab": "0.000-86.261",
  "lvb": "0.000-86.160",
  "ismb": 16480000,
  "leader": 1,
  "relative_loudness": "-9.010",
  "optimal_format": "480p",
  "user_qual": 0,
  "release_version": "youtube.player.web_20230314_01_RC00",
  "debug_videoId": "sILEQ-doSos",
  "0sz": "false",
  "op": "",
  "yof": "false",
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "ANGLE_(Intel,_Mesa_Intel(R)_UHD_Graphics_630_(CML_GT2),_OpenGL_4.6)",
  "debug_playbackQuality": "large",
  "debug_date": "Tue Mar 21 2023 16:35:21 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
}
```

and this is the debug info for a youtube video where the audio *does* work:

```
{
  "ns": "yt",
  "el": "detailpage",
  "cpn": "55DLZLr3OMjXh9xX",
  "ver": 2,
  "cmt": "3.054",
  "fmt": "248",
  "fs": "0",
  "rt": "5.811",
  "euri": "",
  "lact": 1,
  "cl": "516646855",
  "mos": 0,
  "state": "4",
  "volume": 20,
  "cbr": "Chrome",
  "cbrver": "111.0.0.0",
  "c": "WEB",
  "cver": "2.20230320.00.00",
  "cplayer": "UNIPLAYER",
  "cos": "X11",
  "cplatform": "DESKTOP",
  "hl": "en_GB",
  "cr": "CH",
  "len": "551.621",
  "fexp": "23983296,23986033,24004644,24007246,24080738,24135310,24169501,24396645,24415864,24416290,24428638,24433679,24435245,24437577,24439361,24447748,24449113,24450367,24470719,24481771,24482081,24483085,24483088,24487345,24487565,24493698,24493736,24495841,24499792,39323074",
  "afmt": "251",
  "muted": "0",
  "docid": "poEOEkX_FAk",
  "ei": "h84ZZK3MIc--x_APjKaliA4",
  "plid": "AAX3aseklrw-GJQS",
  "of": "2os0eu-f2DdqYkzrhS4TRg",
  "vm": "CAEQARgEOjJBRlNkMkZ2NEFVX0ZndWNBWnpUYklaS25TWWxVeTBCZWVvcVBBS0w1QXdkX0lQT2RaQWJaQVBta0tETENEWEh2WU8xMzdsVWVmRThFSXR4WGRpbzk2S0F2NVRfbU5xNEZOY1FZU2xPbDJjTm40V1JJOW9EamhsaFpRWkZMSFM0RTc1RDBCSVEwZE1xcktBaAE",
  "vct": "3.054",
  "vd": "551.621",
  "vpl": "0.000-3.054",
  "vbu": "0.000-23.200",
  "vpa": "1",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "4",
  "vns": "2",
  "vec": "null",
  "vemsg": "",
  "vvol": "0.2",
  "vdom": "1",
  "vsrc": "1",
  "vw": "2594",
  "vh": "1459",
  "lct": "3.054",
  "lsk": false,
  "lmf": false,
  "lbw": "3526646.199",
  "lhd": "0.249",
  "lst": "0.000",
  "laa": "itag_251_type_3_src_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_seg_2_range_364222-535306_time_20.0-30.0_off_0_len_171085_end_1",
  "lva": "itag_248_type_3_src_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_reslicegetRequestInfoForRange_seg_3_range_912351-2242314_time_17.2-23.2_off_99147_len_1329964_end_1",
  "lar": "itag_251_type_3_src_getRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_getRequestInfoForRange_seg_2_range_364222-535306_time_20.0-30.0_off_0_len_171085_end_1",
  "lvr": "itag_248_type_3_src_getRequestInfoForRange_segsrc_getRequestInfoForRange_seg_3_range_813204-2242314_time_16.7-23.2_off_0_len_1429111_end_1",
  "laq": "0",
  "lvq": "0",
  "lab": "0.000-30.001",
  "lvb": "0.000-23.200",
  "ismb": 16480000,
  "relative_loudness": "-9.270",
  "optimal_format": "1080p",
  "user_qual": 0,
  "release_version": "youtube.player.web_20230314_01_RC00",
  "debug_videoId": "poEOEkX_FAk",
  "0sz": "false",
  "op": "",
  "yof": "false",
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "ANGLE_(Intel,_Mesa_Intel(R)_UHD_Graphics_630_(CML_GT2),_OpenGL_4.6)",
  "debug_playbackQuality": "hd1080",
  "debug_date": "Tue Mar 21 2023 16:34:38 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beats me what the cmt field of that means but

Doesn't work: 5.717
Does Word:    3.054

Looks like a versioning problem of some sort ... but I am babbling. Probably. Good luck and post what you discover!